# Framing problem : How can I solve this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions, trigonometry

Let  $f$  be a function and $(a,b,c,x,y,z)\in \mathbb R ^6$;

We have $f(x,y,z,a,b,c)=7x+9z+\sqrt3 y+\cos(2a)+2a+b+c$

We suppose that : 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+(\cos 2a)^2=4$$
What's the exact framing of $f$
$$ \cdots\text{?}\cdots\le f(x,y,z,a,b,c) \le \cdots\text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use Cauchy inequality:

$$(a_1b_1+...a_nb_n)^2\leq (a_1^2+...+a_n^2)(b_1^2+...+b_n^2)$$

if $n=7$.

Further hint: Take $$(a_1,a_2,...a_7)= (7,9,\sqrt{3},1,2,1,1)$$ and

$$(b_1,b_2,...b_7)= (x,z,y, \cos (2a),a,b,c)$$